# php strip_tags to allow comment

Tags: php, strip-tags

I need to strip all html tags but retain comment lines to extract for info.

Is it even possible?

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<!-->');
```

This doesn't work and i have tried a few different variants.

Comment: Its in the manual: `Note:
HTML comments and PHP tags are also stripped. This is hardcoded and can not be changed with allowable_tags.`, you may need to create a workaround for this, an HTML parser perhaps

Comment: thanks. I'll use preg replace to remove tags and leave out the comments.

Comment: @PotentialCoder just replace comments to something else (entities, for example) and return them back after `strip_tags`.

Answer (score 1):

you can protect your comment before strip them using following code

```
// create a random string for using in replace strings
$random = strtoupper(dechex(rand(0,10000000000)));
// replace comment starts
$html = preg_replace('/<!--/', '@MARKER-START-'. $random.'@', $html);
// replace comment ends
$html = preg_replace('/-->/', '@MARKER-END-'. $random.'@', $html);
// strip all html tags
$html = strip_tags($html);
// replace back comment starts
$html = preg_replace('/@MARKER-START-'. $random.'@/', '<!--', $html);
// replace back comment ends
$html = preg_replace('/@MARKER-END-'. $random.'@/', '-->', $html);
```

Comment: why is it necessary to add random string? is it in case of there is an actual string '@MARKER-START-@' in the comment?

Comment: yes. exactly is for case of there is an actual string '@MARKER-START-@' in the comment

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using strip_tags() use this regular expression:

```
$szRetVal = preg_replace( '%</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>%sim','',$szHTML );
```

Comment: Oops ... the regex got wrong once it got published : '%</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>%sim'